# Variable to store values depending upon button clicked

Tags: php

I am trying to integrate PayU Money Payment Gateway to my website
I have three buttons. Each button holds a different value of amount.
What i exactly want is that if a user clicks button1 then 999 INR must be passed to the payU, on clicking button2 1999 should be passed to payU.

```
if($_POST['d1'] == '999'){  $amount = 999;}if($_POST['d1'] == '1999'){$amount = 1999;}

<input name="d1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger book-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#payment" value="999">
<input name="d1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger book-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#payment" value="1999">
```

Comment: use `name` attribute for button and on submission, check for `isset($_POST['<button_name>'])`

Comment: u should put "payu" in ur flags

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="test1" value="99" />
<input type="submit" name="test1" value="999" />
</form>
```

then ur $_POST['test1'] will be eather 99 or 999.

u can also use

```
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" name="test1" value="99" >99 Cookies ?</button>
<button type="submit" name="test1" value="999" >GIMME 999!</button>
</form>
```

so u can set a Custom text on the button.

## CAREFULL

if u use only $_POST['test1'] and set an value. someone can manipulate the `value="99"` to maybe 9999999 and then ur PayU will take that value.

Comment: already tried this way. but failure.php is executed everytime

Comment: Error at line 20 i.e. if($_POST['d1'] == '1999'){$amount = 1999;}. After the error message it is redirected to failure.php

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: d1 on line 20

Comment: use print_r($_POST) to debug